# Force fit height of font with css or js

Tags: javascript, css

This has been asked long ago in about 2010, but the answers are outdated. I would like to force a font to fit in both height and width.

Currently I have this code:

```
<div class="box" style="width:300px;height:300px; background-color: coral;">
  MY TEXT
</div>
```

Using one of the suggestions found: textFit or any of the other similar scripts.
I can do the following:

[image]

What I would like to achieve is to be able to force it (even though it's unproportional) to do something like this:

[image]

It can be in js or css.  Whichever this way could be accomplished.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let el = document.querySelector(".box");

let width = 300;
let height = 300;

let ws = (width / el.offsetWidth);

let hs = (height / el.offsetHeight);


el.style.transform = `scale(${ws}, ${hs})`;
```

```html
<div class="box" style="display:inline-block; transform-origin: top left; background-color: coral;">
  MY TEXT
</div>
```

You can use `transform: scale(x, y)` property.